# Is there an unwritten etiquette for GTA V lobbies?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I've only racked up about 10 hours in GTA 5 Online (for PC), and so far just having fun in the lobby is fantastic.

However I'm only a Level 10 , so imagine my surprise last night when I went to go to Los Santos Customs and saw about 5 members of a crew, all level 100 or above, in identical cars, driving in a circle formation around the Los Santos Customs car park.

So I did what any self-respecting GTA player would do. I got out my rocket launcher and blew them up. All of them.

This resulted in them getting **mad**. They became verbally abusive (eh, this is not uncommon and doesn't particularly worry me), told me that it's not cool to interrupt when they're "trying to do something" and they all voted to kick me from the session, and BAM I was gone.

In my searches for an answer to this on the internet, I found a lot of people who are very grumpy when people kill them "unprovoked". But I thought that was the point of the game?

I'm not particularly concerned about the incident, but it made me wonder if there's some sort of unofficial etiquette I should have been following?

Comment: On the one hand, I'm fully in favour of "don't be a dick unless provoked". On the other hand a whole swarm of level 100s swarming around the building I (a considerably lower leveled player) just got out of? Yeah, I'm going to assume *I'm* the target of whatever they have planned and take action. Although my preference is passive mode and run away, an explosion *does* give a nice "back the eff off" message.

Comment: Also, keep in mind if their vehicles were expensive and insured; YOU are on the hook for destroying them. So your "shoot rockets first, ask questions later" strategy can end up getting rather expensive for *you*.

Comment: People that shoot first and ask questions later is the reason why most people hate free roaming in GTA Online. Also why I use passive mode around most people...

Comment: A third thing to keep in mind, is that although the ingame insurance exists for the sole purpose of replacing cars lost to random jerkery - it has many bugs associated with it, and those cars you blew up *might* not get replaced as intended, which forces your targets to contact Rockstar Support, which can take upwards of three weeks to resolve.

Comment: You'll also notice that it's mostly low rank people that follow the shoot first, ask question later strategy, and most high rank players are actually quite nice (there's always exceptions, of course).

Comment: So really what you're all saying is that the free-roaming lobby is *not* for blowing each other up? I thought that was the whole point... as for the personal cost of replacing the personal vehicles, I'm OK with that - I consider it the cost of doing business at times.

Comment: @TrentHawkins out of curiosity, what's the reasoning behind running away, instead of standing your ground and fighting? My assumption was that if you're not in passive mode, you're fair game...

Comment: Well, yes, while I'm in passive mode I'm not necessarily running from any immediate threat (let's ignore the possibility of hackers; as they can blow you up, at will, remotely). Thing is, I rarely *maintain* passive mode, as that makes a number of things difficult (Defending myself against overzealous police, destroying targets per [NPC]'s request, robbing convenience stores, completing daily challenges for bonuses...). And there's almost never a good reason to stand your ground when a considerably higher-leveled player is after you, because the ground you stand on is **not** even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in all game lobbies and other idle servers, it's not considered good etiquette to enter combat with people in an area that is clearly not conducting combat.  Generally this is go with the flow.  Don't go all PvP if other players aren't doing the same.

If you are not sure if people age goofing off with combat in an idle server or lobby or if they are goofing off without combat, you can simply ask.   You don't have to go into details.

Still, kicking people from a public lobby for breaking PvP etiquette is not a very polite way to deal with it either, so don't go doing that yourself.

Still, try not to judge others for being jerks, especially when you were accidentally a bit of a jerk.  We've all been jerks once or twice by accident or just from being in a bad mood, and we've all been the victim of jerks, so we should not be judging people over it unless they are mic spamming profanity when they aren't rapping along with the rest of their crew.

p.s. feel free to substitute jerk for a more profane word not appropriate for Stack Exchange but plenty appropriate for GTA V.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand that I was *being* a jerk. From what I understood the lobby was a PvP area and if you didn't want to PvP then go passive. I guess I have misunderstood.

Comment: I've tried this the past few times and it seems to have merit. I even deliberately followed one guy on the freeway just to see if he'd slow down and fire at me, and he just ignored me like I wasn't there and went on his merry way. I've now kept combat just to matches or if I run into a bunch of people already fighting, and people seem happier with me.

Answer (score 1):

Do whatever you want to do. You paid same money as them to play online. If they don't like the way you play, they can change server, go into the passive mode or start a private session.

All parties have options.

Comment: Apparently unpopular opinion. In context of OP's story if I'm trying to do something (like film 5 identical cars driving in circles) I would go to private session or at least put on a passive mode. Not blame other players playing within the limits of the game. Someone might light online races, someone might like bank heists. I'm not gonna kick someone of the server because he has different opinion than I do.

Answer (score 1):

The rules are as follows:

1. Do Not Jet Grief (Only use a jet to take down other aircraft or fly around in it, do not kill people on the ground)
2. Don't tank grief (Unless people attack you or come at you leave them be)
3. Only attack people in self defence (this includes pre-emptive attacking if you believe they are about to attack you)
4. Don't bug people with texts or chat if people don't wanna talk to you don't talk to them (Only message people who are interested in speaking with you)
5. Leave people in passive alone if they follow you get away from them (they're probably planning on killing you sneakily)
6. Don't use mods or modded things (Nobody likes or respects modders the only people that say they do are ones using them for money but they don't mean it)
7. No glitching this means no glitch outfits, wall breaches or other glitches 
   (Use the game as it was meant to be)
8. Only report or kick people who are griefing or modding
9. Don't spam mission invites if people aint interested
10. If people are trying to get away from you don't follow them

You should only kill people and chase people down if they attack you a crew member or friend or kill you.

Using passive mode and off radar are acceptable but people may ridicule you.

Don't spam rockets or overpowered weapons use overpowered weapons as a last resort (People who use overpowered weaponry at the start of a fight look weak and are viewed as noobs)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to mess with people who are higher rank than you are. Mess with people than you can fight and try to be peaceful most of the time only kill them if they kill you. To be honest think if they had killed you and you didnt have an intention to kill them. how would you feel about it???

Comment: Riight, but I thought the whole point of the game *was* to kill each other. Not to be peaceful. You don't buy CoD and then complain that people are not letting you look at the scenery...

Comment: Additionally, it's basically impossible to tell if someone is a high rank than you when they're just a dot on the map. You have to explicitly go and look to see if they're a higher rank. Hard to do in the heat of the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Do whatever you want they can always play single player or passive mode if they don't want to be killed.